# How to sum rows after paging?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a MySQL database that tracks events on a calendar. I have a table called calendar that has all the dates that concern me. At my job we have contracts that have certain values; for the sake of simplification we will use only 1 and 2. These contracts have a start date and a end date. I want to take all the contracts for the whole calendar and add up the contracts values for each day.

So far I have:

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, contract.time_slots AS Slots_taken
FROM contract
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON calendar.datefield
BETWEEN contract.start_time
AND contract.end_time
LIMIT 600 , 30
```

This almost gives me what I want. This query produces a tables like this:

```
    DATE    |  Slots_taken
------------|--------------
2013-08-29  |     1
2013-08-30  |     1
2013-08-31  |     1
2013-09-01  |     1
2013-09-01  |     2
2013-09-02  |     1
2013-09-02  |     2
2013-09-03  |     1
2013-09-03  |     2
```

But here I am getting repeat dates. I want only one row per date with the sum of the values for that date. So it should be:

```
    DATE    |  Slots_taken
------------|--------------
2013-08-29  |     1
2013-08-30  |     1
2013-08-31  |     1
2013-09-01  |     3
2013-09-02  |     3
2013-09-03  |     3
```

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY (or possibly GROUP BY) is fairly meaningless. Note also that while a search for the term "LEFT JOIN" on SO returns approximately 46,237 results, "RIGHT JOIN" comes in at a desultory 2,116. You might want to consider that next time you're structuring your query to use one or the other. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, SUM(contract.time_slots) AS Slots_taken
FROM contract
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON calendar.datefield
BETWEEN contract.start_time
AND contract.end_time
GROUP BY DATE
LIMIT 600 , 30
```

Comment: This is what I tried first, but this give me the whole column summed in to one row. So it would be like: 2013-08-29 | 12

Comment: If this is what you tried first and it gave you one row I suspect you missed `GROUP BY DATE` from the query.

Comment: This also is close, but everything is multiplied by 5. Why is that?

Comment: The rows are grouped before the limit, so rows that are limited out when you weren't using the group by could be included when using group by. This could be why you're seeing higher than expected sums.

Answer (score 1):

if it were plain tSQL, I would suggest SUM() and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, sum(contract.time_slots) AS Slots_taken
FROM contract
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON calendar.datefield
BETWEEN contract.start_time
AND contract.end_time
LIMIT 600 , 30
GROUP BY calendar.datefield
```

baring LIMIT as it is not 'plain' tSQL

hope it helps a bit

EDIT

how about this:

```
 SELECT DATE, SUM(Slots_taken) AS Slots_taken
 FROM (
   SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, contract.time_slots AS Slots_taken
   FROM contract
   RIGHT JOIN calendar ON calendar.datefield
   BETWEEN contract.start_time
   AND contract.end_time
   LIMIT 600 , 30) A
 GROUP BY calendar.datefield
```

Again, it is rather 'plain' tSQL, and this is a joke of a query :)

Comment: Okay so this is weird, but this is actually what I need but everything is multiplied by a factor of 5 so the out put is like `     DATE    |  Slots_taken
------------|--------------
2013-08-29  |     5
2013-08-30  |     5
2013-08-31  |     5
2013-09-01  |     15
2013-09-02  |     15
2013-09-03  |     15 `

Comment: `LIMIT` comes after the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT calendar.datefield date
     , SUM(contract.time_slots) slots_taken
  FROM calendar
  LEFT 
  JOIN calendar 
    ON calendar.datefield BETWEEN contract.start_time AND contract.end_time
 GROUP
    BY date
 LIMIT 600 , 30;
```

Comment: This also gives me all my values multiplied by 5